# Installation of profvis via devtools::install_github fails to find libreadline.a

Tags: r, homebrew, devtools

I am trying to install the R package `profvis` in the following manner:

```
with_envvar(c(LDFLAGS = "-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib",
              CPPFLAGS= "-I/usr/local/opt/readline/include"), 
            devtools::install_github("rstudio/profvis"))
```

However, the error message that I am getting is:

```
...
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -DPLATFORM_PKGTYPE='"mac.binary.mavericks"'    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c pause.c -o pause.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/opt/X11/lib -L/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libcairo.a /usr/local/lib/libpixman-1.a /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.a /usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.a -lxml2 /usr/local/lib/libreadline.a -o profvis.so pause.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/libreadline.a'
make: *** [profvis.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘profvis’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/profvis’
Error: Command failed (1)
```

The location of the library is here:

```
$ ls /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.a 
/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.a
```

Note that I did not choose to symlink into `/usr/local`

```
$ brew info readline
readline: stable 6.3.8 (bottled) [keg-only]
Library for command-line editing
https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html
/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.3.8 (40 files, 2.1M)
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/readline.rb
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.
```

This is because of the warning I got when I typed `brew link readline`:

```
Warning: readline is keg-only and must be linked with --force
Note that doing so can interfere with building software.
```

Should I symlink with the `--force` option, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue when trying to install `hadley/lineprof` from github on Mac OS X 10.11.4 Beta (15E33e), Microsoft R Open 3.2.3 and RStudio 0.99.491.

I decided to force the symlinks for the time of installation and then remove them.
First, I created symlinks:

```
$ brew link --force readline
```

Then in R I installed lineprof:

```
> devtools::install_github("hadley/lineprof")
```

After the successful installation of the lineprof I removed the symlinks:

```
$ brew unlink readline
```

I also had to restart RStudio after linking, but I don't know why that mattered.